# duplicate a column in pyspark data frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame in `pyspark` like sample below. I would like to duplicate a column in the data frame and rename to another column name.

```
Name    Age    Rate
Aira     23     90
Ben      32     98
Cat      27     95
```

Desired output is :

```
Name    Age     Rate     Rate2
Aira    23      90       90
Ben     32      98       98
Cat     27      95       95
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You're looking for the `withColumn()` function: `df = df.withColumn("Rate2", "Rate")` should work. Let me try to find a dupe link...

Comment: See [How do I add a new column to a Spark DataFrame (using PySpark)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681487/how-do-i-add-a-new-column-to-a-spark-dataframe-using-pyspark) and [Adding a new column in Data Frame derived from other columns (Spark)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31333437/adding-a-new-column-in-data-frame-derived-from-other-columns-spark)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just

```
df.withColumn("Rate2", df["Rate"])
```

or (in SQL)

```
SELECT *, Rate AS Rate2 FROM df
```