# how insert value into spark readstream

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, cassandra, spark-structured-streaming

## Source Code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# DataFrame for kafka
schema = StructType() \
        .add("sensor_id", StringType(), True) \
        .add("create_dt", StringType(), True) \
        .add("collect_time", StringType(), True) \
        .add("avg", StringType(), True) \
        .add("data_type", StringType(), True) \
        .add("max", StringType(), True) \
        .add("min", StringType(), True)

###################################### Source Code ######################################

# Spark Bridge local to spark_master
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master(_connSession)\
    .appName("Spark_Streaming+kafka+cassandra") \
    .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', _connCassandraHost) \
    .config('spark.cassandra.connection.port', _connCassandraPort) \
    .getOrCreate()

# readStream From DATA_SOC at DB Server
df = spark.readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", _connKafka) \
  .option('startingOffsets','earliest') \
  .option("subscribe", _topic) \
  .load() \
  .select(from_json(col("value").cast("String"), schema).alias("parsed_value")) \
  .select("parsed_value.*")

df.withColumn("create_dt", lit("collect_time"[0:7]))

df.printSchema()

# writeStream at cassandra in Spark master VM
ds = df.writeStream \
  .trigger(processingTime='15 seconds') \
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
  .option("checkpointLocation","/home/jeju/jeju_sensor_collector/src/checkPoint") \
  .options(table=_table,keyspace=_keySpace) \
  .outputMode('append') \
  .start()

ds.awaitTermination()

root
 |-- sensor_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- create_dt: string (nullable = true)
 |-- collect_time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- avg: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- max: string (nullable = true)
 |-- min: string (nullable = true)
```

## Error

```
com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.NullKeyColumnException: Invalid null value for key column create_dt
```

create_dt value error so I tried

```
df.withColumn("create_dt", lit("collect_time"[0:7]))
```

but still error..... how can i insert value in readstream

create_dt value must be collect_time[0:7]

## example

collect_time value is 2022-10-26 14:30:11.000. and create_dt mute be 202210
and sensor_id&create_dt,collect_time is primary_eky

## Sample Success data on cassandra

[image]

Comment: Do you have a sample entry which is being pushed to the readStream ?

Comment: @Shane edit plus sample iamge

Comment: @Shane sry my mistake upload the other image

Comment: Instread of  `lit("collect_time"[0:7])` try using datetime functions supported by Spark to extract the yyyymm part.

Comment: Refer to this: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-date-and-time-functions/

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde same error : com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.NullKeyColumnException: Invalid null value for key column create_dt
```df.withColumn("create_df",date_format(current_date(),"yyyyMM")```

Comment: #Solved
```df = df.withColumn("create_dt",(df["collect_time"])[0:7])```
this code is copy collect_time[0:7] into create_dt

Refer to this : https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-structtype-and-structfield/#update-struct-function  AND https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399361/duplicate-a-column-in-pyspark-data-frame

Comment: Please add answer below rather than as a comment

Comment: Btw, ideally you *parse* the timestamp and *format* it. Different locales use different time strings, so slicing is a bad idea

Comment: @OneCricketeer i will refer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved Code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# DataFrame for kafka
schema = StructType() \
        .add("sensor_id", StringType(), True) \
        .add("collect_time", StringType(), True) \
        .add("avg", StringType(), True) \
        .add("data_type", StringType(), True) \
        .add("max", StringType(), True) \
        .add("min", StringType(), True)

###################################### Source Code ######################################

# Spark Bridge local to spark_master
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master(_connSession)\
    .appName("Spark_Streaming+kafka+cassandra") \
    .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', _connCassandraHost) \
    .config('spark.cassandra.connection.port', _connCassandraPort) \
    .getOrCreate()

# readStream From DATA_SOC at DB Server
df = spark.readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", _connKafka) \
  .option('startingOffsets','earliest') \
  .option("subscribe", _topic) \
  .load() \
  .select(from_json(col("value").cast("String"), schema).alias("parsed_value")) \
  .select("parsed_value.*")

df = df.withColumn("create_dt", lit("collect_time"[0:7]))


df.printSchema()

# writeStream at cassandra in Spark master VM
ds = df.writeStream \
  .trigger(processingTime='15 seconds') \
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
  .option("checkpointLocation","/home/jeju/jeju_sensor_collector/src/checkPoint") \
  .options(table=_table,keyspace=_keySpace) \
  .outputMode('append') \
  .start()

ds.awaitTermination()
```

I was delete `.add("create_dt", StringType(), True)` cause `df.withColumn` will make **create_dt**. and first time I only typing `df.withColumn("create_dt", lit("collect_time"[0:7]))` but that is not apllied df. so change `df = df.withColumn("create_dt", lit("collect_time"[0:7]))` finally i can apllied